# How to handle overlapping logs with filebeat?

Tags: filebeat, elastic-beats

is there a way to handle overlapping logs with filebeat? here's a sample of what i have:

```
[17/02/2020 07:53:27:748] 00000 I >> message1 (start of event)
[17/02/2020 07:53:27:751] 00000 I @ message2
[17/02/2020 07:53:27:785] 00004 I >> message1 (start of event)
[17/02/2020 07:53:27:787] 00004 I @ message2
[17/02/2020 07:53:27:811] 00004 I  < message3
[17/02/2020 07:53:27:812] 00004 I << message4 (end of event)
[17/02/2020 07:53:27:834] 00000 I  < message3
[17/02/2020 07:53:27:835] 00000 I << message4 (end of event)
```

an event starts with >> and end with << having the same thread number
thanks in advance!